# React native reuse a component issue with componentDidMount not being called

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to reuse a component because I only need to change the data.

I have one main component that includes the reusable component. It should change the reusable component status according to the button selected.

```
...
renderReusable() {
    switch (this.state.selectedButton) {
      case 'Test1':
        return <ReusableComp status="Test1" />;
      case 'Test2':
        return <ReusableComp status="Test2" />;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
...
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button
           primary bordered style={styles.topButtoon}
           onPress={() => this.setState({ selectedButton: 'Test1' })}
        >
            <Text>Test1</Text>
        </Button>
        <Button
            primary bordered style={styles.topButtoon}
            onPress={() => this.setState({ selectedButton: 'Test2' })}
        >
            {this.showSelected('closed')}
            <Text>Test2</Text>
        </Button>
    </View>
    {this.renderReusable()}
</View>
```

Then, in my reusable component, I grab the data according to the props.status

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      myData: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getMyData();
  }

  getMyData = async () => {
    if (this.props.status === 'Test1') {
      await this.props.getTest1();
    } else if (this.props.status === 'Test2') {
      await this.props.getTest2();
    }
    this.setState({
      myData: this.props.data
    });
  };
...
CREATE THE RENDER()
...
```

I'm using redux to grab the data and it is working fine. My problem is that when I click on button Test2 or button Test1 the componentDidMount from reusable component is not being called, so it doesn't call the methods to get data. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does.

`componentDidMount` gets called only the first time the component is mounted.

In this case you have to use `componentDidUpdate` that does exactly what you need: detects that new data has come and makes your component aware of it.

```
componentDidUpdate=(prevProps)=>{
    if(prevProps!==this.props) this.getMyData()
}
```

As you see, you have to control the current props the component has with the previous ones, if they are different, update the state, else, do nothing.

Rember to always put check inside `componentDidUpdate`, as a setState inside of it will trigger it again, going for an infinite loop.

Hope this helps you solve your problem!